# adding facebook dependency cause method references number to exceed 64K

Tags: java, android, facebook, dex

I have a very simple app in android studio and encountered this bizarre  problem. After adding dependency to facebook sdk

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

to build.gradele I always get an error:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I know it can be solved by using multidex but I guess facebook sdk dependency alone should not bring the number of referenced methods over the 64K limit. 
I will appreciate any hints on this.

Edit: Using multidex solves the problem but I would like to know if this is correct behaviour to hit the dex limit just by refferencing facebook sdk.

Comment: Using multidex solves the problem but I would like to know if this is correct behaviour to hit the dex limit just by refferencing facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is caused by facebook sdk?

It only has 4000 methods far from the 65k. (source: http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.facebook.android%3Afacebook-android-sdk%3A4.9.0)

Maybe something else is big and you only tip over the limit with facebook sdk.